Repair of Philips MCM778 / ought the resistor be changed?
Upon powering on Philips MCM778 transceiver a signaling sound indicated possible lighting up of fuse. Can anyone advise whether the fuse had burnt and R2 resistor burnt? Should I intend to replace R2 (\$ R = 300 \textrm{M} \Omega\$) of Philips MCM778 amplifier?

With fuse T3.15A250Vac - time lag L replaced I see no error in signals for amplifier circuit.
Diode D16:

Resistor R10:

Capacitor C11:

Signal of R2 shows it discharges \$\tau \approx 1 \textrm{ms} \$. Coupled to R2 is capacitor \$ C = 0,01 \mu\textrm{F} \$.


experience tells me that the resistor is the most robust of all components when it comes to overcurrrent. If that resistor burned, all the semiconductor paths in its way are suspect, and quite possibly replacing them completely is less work than debugging which ones bit the dust, specifically

and seeing this is a consumer device: hm. consider the cost of buying a used equivalent device before investing much in repair.

Seeing the voltage on oscilloscope that is fatally dangerous I do not advise testing electrical equipment for risk of short-circuits. The pictures display Picoscope 5242D meas., which is not rated for 220V AC mains supply measurement. It was not expected to be this voltage (because of accidental short-circuit the Picoscope had been repaired due to not-working chip in January '24).
Please help, if this is not expected voltage should the ATX Power good voltage apply to this amplifier Philips MCM 778 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_good_signal)?
